# How to get the character description

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python. I am trying to find a way to get descriptions for Unicode characters

Code:

```
str = "python"+chr(8)
for i in str:
    print(chr(ord(i)))
```

eg:

```
ord(i) = 105
chr(105) = i
```

My problem are non-ASCII Unicode characters like `chr(8)`, I want to retrieve a description like "backspace" in this case.

Comment: I made some changes to your question to improve its readability. You can edit your question, if you feel my edit feel doesn't represent your intentions well.

Comment: The closest built-in feature to this seems to be the `unicodedata` module - but that only handles printable characters ('0' -> 'DIGIT ZERO', for example), not control characters.  You may need to create your own dictionary for the problem cases.

Comment: Thanks MrT for your help

Comment: Thanks Jason harper for your inputs, will create a dictionary...